# Dynamic jQuery content not showing up on Mobile with HTML5

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, coldfusion

I have an HTML5 template that I am replacing static content with dynamic jQuery/ajax generated content. The content displays just fine on a desktop browser like Chrome. When I try to view the content on a mobile device like an iPhone or iPad, the dynamically generated content does not show up. I will post both the static content and the dynamic content.

**Static Content**

```js
     <div class="col-lg-6 wow fadeInLeft">
                        <article class="row row-no-gutter blog-post">
                            <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-6 bg-image"
                                 style="background-image: url('images/page-1_img09.jpg')" data-equal-group="1">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 text-md-left" data-equal-group="1">
                            
                                <div class="blog-post__cnt">
                                 
                                    <h5>some text</h5>
                                    <hr class="sm sm--inset-2 sm-default"/>
                                    
                                    <p>some text</p>

                                    <p>some text</p>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn-link">READ MORE</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </article>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 wow fadeInRight">
                        <article class="row row-no-gutter blog-post">
                            <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-6 bg-image pull-sm-right pull-lg-left"
                                 style="background-image: url('images/page-1_img10.jpg')" data-equal-group="1"></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 text-md-left" data-equal-group="1">
                            
                                <div class="blog-post__cnt">
                                    <h5>some text</h5>
                                    <hr class="sm sm--inset-2 sm-default"/>
                                    
                                    <p>some text</p>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn-link">READ MORE</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </article>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 wow fadeInLeft">
                        <article class="row row-no-gutter blog-post">
                            <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-6 bg-image pull-lg-right"
                                 style="background-image: url('images/page-1_img11.jpg')" data-equal-group="2"></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 text-md-left" data-equal-group="2">
                            
                                <div class="blog-post__cnt">
                                    <h5>some text</h5>
                                    <hr class="sm sm--inset-2 sm-default"/>
                                    
                                    <p>some text</p>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn-link">READ MORE</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </article>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 wow fadeInRight">
                        <article class="row row-no-gutter blog-post">
                            <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-6 bg-image pull-sm-right"
                                 style="background-image: url('images/page-1_img12.jpg')" data-equal-group="2"></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 text-md-left" data-equal-group="2">
                                <div class="blog-post__cnt">
                                    <h5>some text</h5>
                                    <hr class="sm sm--inset-2 sm-default"/>
                                    
                                    <p>some text</p>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn-link">READ MORE</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </article>
                    </div>
```

**Dynamic Content**

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var html = "";
 
  function assetsPost() {
  $.ajax({
     cache: false,
     type:'GET',
     url:'cfc/cfc_Forum.cfc?method=getMessages&returnformat=json',
     dataType: "json",
     data: {
      maxRows:  4,
      origin: 1,
    },
     success:function(data) {
    if(data) {   // DO SOMETHING 
    jQuery.each(data, function(i, val) {    
      $('#messages').html(data[i].annotation);
      var threadID   = data[i].thread;
      var BodyText   = data[i].body;
      var name  = data[i].name;
      var MessageID = data[i].MessageID;
      var photo  = data[i].photo;
      var annotation = data[i].annotation;
        if(i == 0) {
        html += "<div class='col-lg-6 wow fadeInLeft'>";
        html += "<article class='row row-no-gutter blog-post'>";
      html += "<div class='col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-6 bg-image' style='background-image: url(" + photo + ")' data-equal-group='1'></div>";
      html += "<div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6 text-md-left' data-equal-group='1'>";
      }
      else if(i == 1) {
      html += "<div class='col-lg-6 wow fadeInRight'>";
        html += "<article class='row row-no-gutter blog-post'>";
      html += "<div class='col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-6 bg-image pull-sm-right pull-lg-left' style='background-image: url(" + photo + ")' data-equal-group='1'></div>";
      html += "<div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6 text-md-left' data-equal-group='1'>";
      }
      else if(i == 2){
      html += "<div class='col-lg-6 wow fadeInLeft'>";
        html += "<article class='row row-no-gutter blog-post'>";
      html += "<div class='col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-6 bg-image pull-lg-right' style='background-image: url(" + photo + ")' data-equal-group='1'></div>";
      html += "<div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6 text-md-left' data-equal-group='2'>";
      }
      else if(i == 3){
      html += "<div class='col-lg-6 wow fadeInRight'>";
        html += "<article class='row row-no-gutter blog-post'>";
      html += "<div class='col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-6 bg-image pull-sm-right' style='background-image: url(" + photo + ")' data-equal-group='1'></div>";
      html += "<div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6 text-md-left' data-equal-group='2'>";
      }
       html += "<div class='blog-post__cnt'>";
      
      html += "<h5>" + name + "</h5>"
      html += "<hr class='sm sm--inset-2 sm-default'/>";
      html += "<p>" + BodyText.substr(0, 400) + "</p>";
      html += "<a href='#' class='btn-link'>READ MORE</a>";    
       
        html += "</div>";
        html += "</div>";
        html += "</article>";
        html += "</div>";
    });
      $('#qMessage').html( html );
    } else { // DO SOMETHING 
     }
   }
  });
 }  
 assetsPost();  
 </script>
```

Any help is well appreciated.

Comment: I just realized that the content does not show up in Firefox either. arg...

Comment: Found my own issue. It was a problem with the coldfusion user authentication. There was nothing wrong with the code! Yes!

Answer (score 0):

Found my own issue. It was a problem with the coldfusion user authentication.

Comment: Do you have any information on how you found the authentication error. Having that information will make this question and answer more useful.

Comment: James, the authentication error was due to the fact that I was not logged into the site on the mobile device that I was testing from. It was not a public page. Once I logged in, I could see it.